# get new captcha in simple-math-captcha django without page reloading

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm using django 1.8.5 with simple-math-captcha. The problem is how to get new captcha via ajax.

comment_form.html:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            {{form.captcha}}
            <span class="error" id="comment-error-captcha"></span>
        </div>
```

forms.py:

```
class AddCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    captcha = MathCaptchaField(widget=MathCaptchaWidget(question_tmpl=u'<label for="id_captcha_0">What is the answer %(num1)i %(operator)s %(num2)i? </label>'))
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddCommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['captcha'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

I don't know how to get new captcha without reloading the page, please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
class GetNewCaptcha(View):

def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    r = {}
    form = AddCommentForm()
    token = self.get_or_create_csrf_token(request)
    r['token'] = token
    r['captcha'] = str(form['captcha'])
    return JsonResponse(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to use ajax reload, but simple-math-captcha doesn't provide this solution. You may overwrite this module and add ajax refresh or use another one. I use in my project [django-simple captcha](https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha) it comes already with ajax refreshing.
For instance:

## html:

```
<form action='.' method='POST'>
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" />
    <button class='js-captcha-refresh'></button>
</form>
```

## javascript:

```
$('.js-captcha-refresh').click(function(){
    $form = $(this).parents('form');

    $.getJSON($(this).data('url'), {}, function(json) {
        // This should update your captcha image src and captcha hidden input
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: "simple-math-captcha doesn't provide this solution", are you absolutely sure?